# (C) Strange crash when using feof

Tags: c, file, crash, cstring

```
    char *headerString = strstr(line, "...\">");
    printf("%d", feof(site));                                   //all is ok
    sscanf(headerString, "...\">%[^<]", tempQuestion.header);
    printf("%d", feof(site));                                   //crash
```

I am completely puzzled why it crashes. I mean, sscanf doesn't do anything with FILE *site, why would it possibly crash?

EDIT:
tempQuestion.header is (char *). What else would you like to know? Everything befor this part worked good. I guess, that I am getting access violation error then program crashes. Using debugger I found out that after the sscanf is done **site** address changes.

Comment: What is `tempQuestion.header`, show us more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If (effectively, I know this is illegal declaration but is for illustration):

```
char* tempQuestion.header;
```

Then before writing to `header` it *must* be pointing at valid memory, otherwise the behaviour is undefined and could be the reason for the behaviour witnessed at `feof`. To correct `malloc` sufficient memory for `header` before using in `sscanf`.

Equally, what if `strstr` returns `NULL`? This would be passed to `sscanf` which would dereference it causing undefined behaviour (again).

Summary:

- ensure `header` is pointing at valid memory
- ensure `strstr` does not return `NULL`